# Removing MySql Membership Provider with ASP.NET tables

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC ,where I have to use MySql Membership provider. After making all the necessary configurations I am able to generate the tables for membership provider. Here , I am not quite sure about a few tables which are generated automatically and want to ask that will it cause any harm if I delete any of them. Furthermore I also need to know for which purpose the following tables are used:

- my_aspnet_schemaversion
- my_aspnet_sessioncleanup
- my_aspnet_sessions

Following is the list of tables generated. A few of them without the "my_asp" prefix are tables which I have created myself.

[image]